# Find index of substring in Racket

Tags: string, racket

I read through [Racket's string library](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html) but couldn't find a function equivalent to Java/JavaScript's [`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String,%20int)) method. That is, is there a function that returns the index of the first character of a substring within a larger string; preferably one that takes an optional start parameter. Something like:

```
(string-index "foobar" "bar")
;;; returns 3
```

I'd be happy with something like lists' [`member`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._member%29%29) function.

Comment: I don't think you would be happy with something that worked like member, which checks against members of a sequence; you want to check against subsequences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a lot of string operations available in SRFI 13. Among these are `string-contains` which does exactly what you want.

```
#lang racket
(require srfi/13) ; the string SRFI    
(string-contains "foobar" "bar")   ; evaluates to 3
```

See more here: [SRFI 13](http://docs.racket-lang.org/srfi/srfi-std/srfi-13.html?q=string-index#string-contains)

FWIW here is a naive implementation of `string-index`

```
(define (string-index hay needle)
  (define n (string-length needle))
  (define h (string-length hay))
  (and (<= n h) ; if the needle is longer than hay, then the needle can not be found
       (for/or ([i (- h n -1)]
                #:when (string=? (substring hay i (+ i n)) needle))
         i)))

(string-index "foobar" "bar")
```

Answer (score 3):

In Racket there is no such primitive function, but you can use [regular expressions](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/regexp.html), for instance:

```
(regexp-match-positions "example" "This is an example.")
=> '((11 . 18))
```